# Telegram Get Channel Profile Photo using Bot API

Tags: rest, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to get the profile picture of a channel in Telegram. According to this doc: 
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

I first try to use getChat to get the basic information about a channel . Which I get successfully. It gives me a json like this:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"id":-1001003587533,"title":"\u06a9\u0627\u0641","username":"kafiha","type":"channel"}}
```

After this I try to use 'getUserProfilePhotos' to get the profile photo. But I can't get it to work because it responds with error when I either pass the id I got from the last request or the channeld username (@channelName).

Do you know how can I accomplish this using Bot API for Telegram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After using `getChat(chat_id)`, if the channel has got a photo, it returns an object which includes a photo object, then you can get `photo.big_file_id` and use `getFile(photo.big_file_id)` to get the full link of the downloadable channel photo. if `getChat(chat_id)` returned object does not include a photo, then it means channel does not have a profile photo

Here is more info on Telegram's documentation. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile

Comment: This is the correct answer...almost. You actually use https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile

Answer (score 0):

It's not available now in Bot API. **getUserProfilePhotos** method require `user_id` parameter, not `chat_id` as you tryed.